# Stop Macro if MsgBox appears

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Macro that performs a few validations. I've simplified the code below for illustration.

- If all the validations are successful, then I want it to run the "ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs" line.
- If a MsgBox has to popup, then I don't want to run the "ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs" line

How could I tweak my code to make this possible? Thank you for helping me!

```
Sub blank()

'Validations
If Cells(10, 4).Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please fill in Invoice Date"
End If

If Cells(11, 4).Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please fill in Invoice Number"
End If

'Save As
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:="Lease Admin Processing Input Form"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this

```
Sub blank()

Dim bolChecker as boolean

bolChecker = false

'Validations
If Cells(10, 4).Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please fill in Invoice Date"
bolChecker = true
End If

If Cells(11, 4).Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please fill in Invoice Number"
bolChecker = true
End If

'Save As
if bolChecker = false then ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:="Lease Admin Processing Input Form"

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes! This works perfectly! Especially helpful as I have many validations, thank you! I've marked your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
Sub blank()

    If Cells(10, 4).Value = "" Or Cells(11, 4).Value = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please fill in both Invoice Number and Invoice Date"
    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:="Lease Admin Processing Input Form"
    End If

End Sub
```

Or this if you have many checks:

```
Dim Msg As String

CheckEmpty Cells(10, 4), Msg, "Invoice date is required"
CheckEmpty Cells(11, 4), Msg, "Invoice number is required"
'...more checks

If len(Msg) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "Please correct the following items:" & vblf & Msg
Else
    'save etc
End If

'....

'utility sub for building notification message
Sub CheckEmpty(c as Range, byRef Msg as string, errMsg As String) 
    If Len(Trim(c.Value)) = 0 Then
        Msg = Msg & vbLf & " - " & errMsg
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if both the validations are true. If they both are true then run the Save As part, otherwise it will skip to save as :)

```
Sub blank()

'Validations
If Cells(10, 4).Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please fill in Invoice Date"
End If

If Cells(11, 4).Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Please fill in Invoice Number"
End If

If Cells(10, 4).Value = "" And Cells(11, 4).Value = "" Then
'Save As
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:="Lease Admin Processing Input Form"
End If
End Sub
```